# How to convert hours, minutes, second in PowerBI to minutes?

Tags: time, powerbi, format

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have a table named `Table1` with a column showing Time Taken for student to finish the exam (as shown in the screenshot above). May I know how should I convert the column to minutes? Basically need to convert `hrs` (if exist) to minutes and convert `sec` to minute as well.

To simplify the output, if the `sec` more than or equal to 30sec, then counted as 1 min, otherwise just ignore the `sec`. I'm still new to PowerBI, any help will be greatly appreciated!

### Output from suggested answer

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform these below steps in your table to get your desired output-

**Advance Query Editor** code

```
let
    //... your previous steps,
    // Change the PREVIOUS STEP NAME accordingly in the NEXT line


    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"PREVIOUS STEP NAME"," hrs","hrs",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Time Taken"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value1"," min","min",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Time Taken"}),
    #"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value"," sec","sec",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Time Taken"}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Replaced Value2", "Time Taken", "Time Taken - Copy"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Duplicated Column", "Time Taken - Copy", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Time Taken - Copy.1", "Time Taken - Copy.2", "Time Taken - Copy.3"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Time Taken - Copy.1", type text}, {"Time Taken - Copy.2", type text}, {"Time Taken - Copy.3", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value3" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type1",null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Time Taken - Copy.1", "Time Taken - Copy.2", "Time Taken - Copy.3"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value3", "hrs", each if Text.PositionOf([#"Time Taken - Copy.1"],"hrs") > 0 then Text.Replace([#"Time Taken - Copy.1"],"hrs","")
else if Text.PositionOf([#"Time Taken - Copy.2"],"hrs") > 0 then Text.Replace([#"Time Taken - Copy.2"],"hrs","")
else if Text.PositionOf([#"Time Taken - Copy.3"],"hrs") > 0 then Text.Replace([#"Time Taken - Copy.3"],"hrs","")
else "0"),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "min", each if Text.PositionOf([#"Time Taken - Copy.1"],"min") > 0 then Text.Replace([#"Time Taken - Copy.1"],"min","")
else if Text.PositionOf([#"Time Taken - Copy.2"],"min") > 0 then Text.Replace([#"Time Taken - Copy.2"],"min","")
else if Text.PositionOf([#"Time Taken - Copy.3"],"min") > 0 then Text.Replace([#"Time Taken - Copy.3"],"min","")
else "0"),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "sec", each if Text.PositionOf([#"Time Taken - Copy.1"],"sec") > 0 then Text.Replace([#"Time Taken - Copy.1"],"sec","")
else if Text.PositionOf([#"Time Taken - Copy.2"],"sec") > 0 then Text.Replace([#"Time Taken - Copy.2"],"sec","")
else if Text.PositionOf([#"Time Taken - Copy.3"],"sec") > 0 then Text.Replace([#"Time Taken - Copy.3"],"sec","")
else "0"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Time Taken - Copy.1", "Time Taken - Copy.2", "Time Taken - Copy.3"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"hrs", Int64.Type}, {"min", Int64.Type}, {"sec", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type2", "final_minutes", each ([hrs]*60) + [min] + (if [sec]>=30 then 1 else 0))
in
    #"Added Custom3"
```

Sample output-

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for your solution! It works for most of the data, but when it comes to `1hrs 47sec` , `25min` or `1hrs`, the output is an error. How should I change it so that it fit for all condition?

Comment: I tried the latest code, but seems like still the same, I attached a screenshot for the output in my question. I will still get error for `25min` and `1hrs 47sec`

Comment: Do you have "and" in the string?

Comment: Nope, only `hrs`, `min`, `sec` in the Time Taken column

Comment: Oh, got it. you have time in some other pattern. I will check that. do you have only second like "25 sec" as well?

Comment: yes, there are some data only have `hrs`, `min` or even only `sec'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240495/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-weizer).